# Using remove or hide function

Tags: jquery

I understand how to use the remove/hide function inside of jQuery however this becomes a little tricky for me.

I have a dropdown that has an if statement based on its selection. If the selection is 0 (which is the default) it should remove the datetime textbox's parent div that has the classes of `section` and `_100`.

That way the whole part of that row in the form is removed. Obviously if the user selects "no" (value is `0`) then it stays removed, and if they user selects "yes" then it shows that whole row so that the user can fill in the datetime the comments expire.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMHkG

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Is that the correct jsfiddle?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here instead of solely posting it externally.

Comment: "section 100" is not a valid className. Do you mean it has multiple classes, `section` and `100`, or `section-100` or `section100`?

Comment: what have you tried? By the way, you can't post a complete HTML document into jsfiddle, it will put that document inside the body element of another document, so it won't work properly.

Comment: Yes it is the right one.

Comment: @Andrew why? I think that rule of not posting other sites is when it isn't jsfiddle,jsbin or other pastebins.

Comment: It is separate classes. If you notice in the form each form element has a <div class="section 100">

Comment: Can you just put the code that matters in the jsfiddle

Comment: Putting `section 100` in a class attribute means that the element will have two classes: `section` and `100` I'm not sure if that is what you want though

Comment: @AnishGupta Any site—JSFiddle & Pastebin included—could disappear, and don't offer any guarantee that content will be around forever. If it goes away, the post becomes useless, further, now the user posted a different link in a comment, but the original post still contains the original. Had the code just resided in the question, it would have been edited here and there would be no confusion.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall True, but some Meta answer said that it's OK to use a pastebin.

Comment: @AnishGupta Well the poster isn't using Pastebin…

Comment: I'm having the feeling nobody is able to understand what I"m trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I think a pastebin means any place that allows its users to upload snippets of text, usually samples of source code, for public viewing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin

Comment: @AnishGupta Also please see [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code) which discourages only posting links to code on an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to the jsFiddle you provided which does what I think you were asking for. You can find the updated version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMHkG/1/) (code below).

I used the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) jQuery function to get a reference to the `<div>` element that you want to hide in relation to the `#datetime` input, since it's not the immediate parent.

Then I changed the `if` statement to use the `===` operator, which compares values without modifying the types, and changed the value being compared against to the string `'0'` rather than the int `0`.

I removed the `else if` because it didn't seem to serve any practical purpose, you only want to do something when the value is equal to `'0'`; if that's not correct, you can always modify the code a bit to do that.

---

HTML:

```
<div class="section _100">
    <label for="comments">Allow Comments</label>
    <div>
        <select name="comments" id="comments">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select An Option</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section _100">
    <label for="datetime">Date Comments Expire</label>
    <div>
        <input id="datetime" type="datetime" name="datetime" />
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var dt= $("#datetime");
var dtparent = dt.closest('div.section._100');

$('#comments').change(function(){

    if($(this).val()==='0'){
        dt.val(''); //empty value
        dt.prop('disabled', true);
        dtparent.hide();
    }
    else{        
        dtparent.show();
        dt.removeAttr('disabled');                    
        dt.attr('validation','true');
    }    
});
```

Comment: Perfect, however, I think I want to have it hidden on page load too.

Comment: @user1333299 Hiding elements is very mundane with jQuery: `$('#xxx').hide();` hides an element which id is "xxx". Add this id after `class="section _100"` (the second one) and it's hidden on page load. (But it's only hidden afterwards if the allowed comments is set to "No". You may want to modify the `$('#comments').change(function()...`.)